# Is there a function or a solution to source from different sheet (and file) based on criteria? WITHOUT VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, criteria

What I am basicaly looking for is a way to lookup data from 1 sheet/file named "`Sheet 2021`" in case the part of lookup value is "`XYZ/21`" and for it to look in "`Sheet 2022`" from another file in case the lookup value is "`XYZ/22`" In addition to that it needs to have multiple criteria as the 2nd lookup value is a 10 digit code.

Example:

I have sheet called "`Claims 2022`" and Sheet called "`Claims 2021`"

Listed values in 1st (RMA 2021):

| RMA | Date of issue | Item Number | Finished? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28/20 | 2/5/2020 | 1234567890 | Yes |
| 1/21 | 3/6/2021 | 1234567890 | No |
| 1/21 | 3/6/2021 | 0987654321 | Yes |
| 1/21 | 3/6/2021 | 1111111111 | No |
| 1/22 | 1/1/2022 | 2222222222 | Yes |

Listed values in 2nd (RMA 2022):

| RMA | Date of issue | Item Number | Finished? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14/21 | 11/12/2021 | 1234567890 | Yes |
| 2/22 | 3/7/2022 | 1234567890 | No |
| 20/22 | 3/6/2022 | 0987654321 | Yes |
| 20/22 | 3/6/2022 | 1111111111 | No |
| 22/22 | 4/8/2022 | 2222222222 | No |

- I want to:

  - extract these in a single file based on the date (If it is issued in 2021).
  - And then extract the value for "Finished".

The reason that numbers do not match the year is because the supply chain program lists them out based on the date of arrival. And I cannot influence or add anything to the source excel.

I don't want a brute force solution such as "if date 21 then 21" through a helper column as the file is gonna expand with other years.

Perhaps there is a function or a possibility to change the source depending on value?
For example:

```
[Source.xlsx]RMA `<value>`'!$C$3:$C$150
```

Where `<value>` would change based on 2020,2021,2022...

Or perhaps there is a more intuitive solution?

Comment: It sounds like a "unique" value for the lookup is a combination of the RMA code and the Item Number? Yes, you could create a helper column. You can also look at creating a `Dictionary`- the "key" would be a concatenated string of RMA & Item Number and the value would be either the row number or an object with the data itself. Lookups are very fast using a dictionary.

Comment: What is the expected output. Please check this: [Help Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: @PeterT, yes I am using a helper column to combine those 2 values for vlookup, but the issue is that I need to check for the matching value in multiple different sheets and I don't know how.

Comment: @DavidLeal, value from another column. Like "finished?". I would need multiple values but I will just use the same function in another column with different resulting value.